# How to evaluate if a door is hung correctly?

Tags: doors

I do not have experience hanging doors and I would like to understand how to evaluate an installed door replacement.  Any list of good checks / verification is appreciated.  My gut tells me this is a fine art and that there may be a few not so obvious checks that come only with experience.  If you have hung 10+ doors please state this in your reply.

Comment: What really matters to humans is that it doesn't _look_ crooked, it opens and closes quietly and smoothly, is secure and solid when closed, and doesn't self-swing open or closed, even part-way.

Comment: So hang it: https://www.pinterest.ch/pin/405112928976949821/

Comment: @SolarMike.    Clever how they intentionally hung it so as to appear crooked

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Plumb, level, square.
2. On plane (not necessarily with respect to the wall, which may be twisted or otherwise distorted).
3. Uniform, appropriate gaps. This includes slab-to-jamb spacing as well as under the door for carpeting, rugs, thresholds, etc.
4. Solid attachment, especially at the hinges and strike plate.
5. Smooth, quiet operation with no gravity-induced movement.
6. Proper weather sealing, where appropriate.

*<sub>Experience claim: Hundreds (thousands?) of interior and exterior doors installed or refurbished over 30 years.</sub>*

Comment: I agree not only gravity movement but a hinge that is out of line can cause a sprung door but your other items really cover this.

Comment: Can we take advantage of gravity to ensure that the door is kept closed (or opened)?

Comment: 7. If door(s) are interior, decide on gap at bottom of door, for smooth operation, possibility of adding carpet or other flooring.